# Pandas change values in pandas dataframe based on a slice with selected indexes and shift()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe `df`. First I filter it, then I need to find all rows that satisfy a criteria and then mark all these rows plus 2 previous rows for each in a specific bool column in the original dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({{'A': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 1944.09, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: 1926.0, 6: nan, 7: 1930.31, 8: nan, 9: nan, 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan, 14: nan, 15: 1917.66, 16: 1920.43, 17: nan, 18: 1909.04, 19: nan, 20: nan, 21: nan, 22: nan, 23: nan, 24: 1920.05, 25: nan, 26: 1915.4, 27: 1921.87, 28: nan, 29: nan, 30: nan, 31: 1912.42, 32: 1920.08, 33: 1915.8, 34: nan, 35: nan, 36: nan, 37: nan, 38: 1919.71, 39: 1916.2, 40: nan, 41: 1926.79, 42: nan, 43: 1918.66, 44: nan, 45: 1925.5, 46: 1922.22, 47: nan, 48: nan, 49: 1927.87, 50: 1923.24, 51: nan, 52: 1929.53, 53: nan, 54: nan, 55: nan, 56: nan, 57: nan, 58: nan, 59: nan, 60: nan, 61: 1918.37, 62: nan, 63: nan, 64: 1923.61, 65: nan, 66: 1917.1, 67: nan, 68: nan, 69: nan, 70: nan, 71: nan, 72: nan, 73: nan, 74: nan, 75: nan, 76: nan, 77: nan, 78: nan, 79: nan, 80: nan, 81: 1924.48, 82: nan, 83: nan, 84: 1923.03, 85: nan, 86: nan, 87: nan, 88: nan, 89: 1926.87, 90: nan, 91: nan, 92: nan, 93: 1921.79, 94: nan, 95: 1925.27, 96: nan, 97: 1919.0, 98: nan, 99: nan, 100: 1923.74, 101: nan, 102: nan, 103: nan, 104: nan, 105: 1911.61, 106: nan, 107: 1923.33, 108: nan, 109: nan, 110: nan, 111: 1912.0, 112: nan, 113: 1915.8, 114: nan, 115: 1913.05, 116: nan, 117: nan, 118: nan, 119: nan, 120: nan, 121: nan, 122: 1916.93, 123: nan, 124: 1913.69, 125: nan, 126: nan, 127: nan, 128: nan, 129: 1918.38, 130: 1913.7, 131: nan, 132: nan, 133: nan, 134: nan, 135: nan, 136: 1919.5, 137: nan, 138: 1916.14, 139: nan, 140: nan, 141: nan, 142: nan, 143: nan, 144: 1921.28, 145: nan, 146: nan, 147: nan, 148: nan, 149: nan, 150: 1915.0, 151: nan, 152: nan, 153: nan, 154: nan, 155: nan, 156: 1927.48, 157: 1889.17, 158: nan, 159: 1921.91, 160: 1917.67, 161: 1923.23, 162: nan, 163: nan, 164: nan, 165: 1909.88, 166: nan, 167: 1913.82, 168: 1902.51, 169: nan, 170: nan, 171: nan, 172: nan, 173: nan, 174: nan, 175: nan, 176: nan, 177: nan, 178: nan, 179: 1920.15}, 'C': {0: False, 1: False, 2: True, 3: False, 4: False, 5: False, 6: False, 7: False, 8: False, 9: False, 10: False, 11: False, 12: False, 13: False, 14: False, 15: False, 16: False, 17: False, 18: False, 19: False, 20: False, 21: False, 22: False, 23: False, 24: False, 25: False, 26: False, 27: True, 28: False, 29: False, 30: False, 31: False, 32: True, 33: False, 34: False, 35: False, 36: False, 37: False, 38: False, 39: False, 40: False, 41: True, 42: False, 43: False, 44: False, 45: False, 46: False, 47: False, 48: False, 49: False, 50: False, 51: False, 52: True, 53: False, 54: False, 55: False, 56: False, 57: False, 58: False, 59: False, 60: False, 61: False, 62: False, 63: False, 64: False, 65: False, 66: False, 67: False, 68: False, 69: False, 70: False, 71: False, 72: False, 73: False, 74: False, 75: False, 76: False, 77: False, 78: False, 79: False, 80: False, 81: False, 82: False, 83: False, 84: False, 85: False, 86: False, 87: False, 88: False, 89: True, 90: False, 91: False, 92: False, 93: False, 94: False, 95: False, 96: False, 97: False, 98: False, 99: False, 100: False, 101: False, 102: False, 103: False, 104: False, 105: False, 106: False, 107: True, 108: False, 109: False, 110: False, 111: False, 112: False, 113: False, 114: False, 115: False, 116: False, 117: False, 118: False, 119: False, 120: False, 121: False, 122: False, 123: False, 124: False, 125: False, 126: False, 127: False, 128: False, 129: False, 130: False, 131: False, 132: False, 133: False, 134: False, 135: False, 136: False, 137: False, 138: False, 139: False, 140: False, 141: False, 142: False, 143: False, 144: False, 145: False, 146: False, 147: False, 148: False, 149: False, 150: False, 151: False, 152: False, 153: False, 154: False, 155: False, 156: True, 157: False, 158: False, 159: False, 160: False, 161: True, 162: False, 163: False, 164: False, 165: False, 166: False, 167: False, 168: False, 169: False, 170: False, 171: False, 172: False, 173: False, 174: False, 175: False, 176: False, 177: False, 178: False, 179: False}})

df2 = df[df.C]
print(df2)

2      1944.09
27     1921.87
32     1920.08
41     1926.79
52     1929.53
89     1926.87
107    1923.33
156    1927.48
161    1923.23
Name: A, dtype: float64

df3 = df2[(df2.A > df2.A.shift(1)) & (df2.A.shift(1) > df2.A.shift(2))]
print(df3)

52    1929.53
Name: A, dtype: float64

df[FROM_2nd_PREVIOUS_TO_EVERY_ROW_OF_df3_IN_df2:TO_EVERY_ROW_IN_df3, 'B'] = True
print(df)
           A        B
0        NaN    False
..       ...      ...
31   1234.56    False
32   1920.08    True
33   1234.56    True
..       ...      ...
41   1926.79    True
40   1234.56    True
..       ...      ...
51   1234.56    True
52   1929.53    True
52   1234.56    False
..       ...      ...
176      NaN    False
177      NaN    False
178      NaN    False
179  1920.15    False
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: @PierreD I've added an example.

Comment: Do you mean `df2 = df[~df["A"].isna()]`? *(Your code appears to be a syntax error.)*  Why doesn't row 179 appear in df2?  Why does `A` have more non-NaN values in df3 than in df2?  *(Please read [mre] and then edit your question to be complete, accurate and consistent.)*  What should happen if df3 contains more than one row?

Comment: @MatBailie I corrected ```df2```.  If ```df3``` has multiple returns, this needs to happen to all of them.

Comment: It's still not consistent...  You have rows in `df3["A"]` that are greater than 0, which are not greater than 0 in `df` *(row 31, for example)*...  Your [mre] should be able to be run by us, with our answer at the end, and generate your desired results.

Comment: @MatBatryiilie My bad. My actual code has a lot more fields and filters, I was trying to simplify it and made some mistakes.

Comment: Please give us the entire `df['A']` in the form `df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [list of all 180 values] })`; then we can work through your logic with the actual data and compare results with what you expect.

Comment: @Nick Added the entire ```df['A']```

Comment: Make this do what you think it should do, then fix your question: https://trinket.io/python3/061701845a

Comment: For your sample data, `df3` is empty.

Comment: @Nick That's because I was actually filtering on another column "C", that I omitted in the question. I really thought it was a very simple question where the answer would be just one line and nobody would have to try to replicate the code. Anyway I've updated the ```df```.

Comment: Your data still doesn't seem to do what you described, so I made this for you : https://trinket.io/python3/1f86a22ab3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a mask from the ascending value condition, and then use `np.flatnonzero` to find the indexes of all the `True` values in it; those results can then be used to index into the filtered values to find the range of values needed to be set `True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [nan, nan, 1944.09, nan, nan, 1926.0, nan, 1930.31, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1917.66, 1920.43, nan, 1909.04, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1920.05, nan, 1915.4, 1921.87, nan, nan, nan, 1912.42, 1920.08, 1915.8, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1919.71, 1916.2, nan, 1926.79, nan, 1918.66, nan, 1925.5, 1922.22, nan, nan, 1927.87, 1923.24, nan, 1929.53, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1918.37, nan, nan, 1923.61, nan, 1917.1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1924.48, nan, nan, 1923.03, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1926.87, nan, nan, nan, 1921.79, nan, 1925.27, nan, 1919.0, nan, nan, 1923.74, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1911.61, nan, 1923.33, nan, nan, nan, 1912.0, nan, 1915.8, nan, 1913.05, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1916.93, nan, 1913.69, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1918.38, 1913.7, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1919.5, nan, 1916.14, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1921.28, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1915.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1927.48, 1889.17, nan, 1921.91, 1917.67, 1923.23, nan, nan, nan, 1909.88, nan, 1913.82, 1902.51, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1920.15], 'C': [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]})

# filter by df.C
a = df[df.C]['A']

# generate mask
mask = (a > a.shift(1)) & (a.shift(1) > a.shift(2))

# get indexes of values which need to be true
idxs = itertools.chain.from_iterable(range(a.index[i-2], a.index[i]+1) for i in np.flatnonzero(mask))

# and set B
df['B'] = df.index.isin(set(idxs))

# this will almost certainly be faster
df['B'] = False
df.loc[idxs, 'B'] = True
```

Output:

```
           A      C      B
0        NaN  False  False
1        NaN  False  False
...
31   1912.42  False  False
32   1920.08   True   True
33   1915.80  False   True
...
51       NaN  False   True
52   1929.53   True   True
53       NaN  False  False
...
178      NaN  False  False
179  1920.15  False  False
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought there would be a simple built-in pandas tool to achieve that, but I am a noob in pandas, so maybe I am not seing the whole picture.

Comment: @Viktor there may be a simpler solution but certainly there's nothing built-in that I can think of. I don't mind if you don't accept this answer to see if you get something better.

Comment: A couple of alternatives for your critique, as `isin()` can be "relatively" costly on large sets? https://trinket.io/python3/055c60f8a0

Comment: @MatBailie the link seems broken?

Comment: @MatBailie I've made a couple of optimisations independently; converting `idxs` to a set for use with `isin`, or using `df.loc` instead.

Comment: @Viktor I've made some slight optimisations to the code which should help if your dataset is large